# Story about aliens giving powers to a weak man

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Aliens visit the village bar and take pity on a meek guy. This weakling is being bullied by village bully. Aliens impart him tremendous physical strength. He starts exhibiting amazing feats.

Comment: Can you give a little more information? When did you read this? Where was this village? Do you remember what the aliens looked like? Cover art for the book?

Comment: Sounds like *The Man Who Could Work Miracles*.  The book was by H.G.Wells and was released as a film in 1937.  However, the powers were granted by the gods on Olympus, not by aliens.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Mr. Dingle, The Strong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Dingle,_the_Strong) from the original Twilight Zone series:

> In an experiment, a two-headed Martian scientist, who is invisible to
> Earthlings, gives vacuum-cleaner salesman and perennial loser Luther
> Dingle superhuman strength. After discovering his inexplicable powers,
> Dingle begins performing various feats of strength, from lifting
> statues to splitting boulders, and gains a great deal of publicity.